# Android Demo's aren't appearing in simulator

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get my feet wet with Android development. I downloaded Eclipse, and setup the ADT. When I create a project from existing source, I choose the demo projects (API Demo) and compile + run. The simulator pops up but I can't seem to find the API Demo application. How can I get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by running /tools/android and setting the base API to 2.2. APK installed fine after that

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file in the project for activities that are marked as launch activities.  They should have something like:

```
<activity . . .>
  <intent-filter . . . >
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

From there you should be able to see the name of the application as it will appear in the app list.

If there are none, than a runnable application won't be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in the output? The emulator can be flaky at times. Try closing the emulator and running it again, or go to the bin/ directory in the project and enter "adb install [packageName].apk" in the shell.

The output should tell you what's wrong when you try to run it. If the above doesn't work, please post the full output.